# Please help me understand the following notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Can someone kindly tell me the meaning of the following notation:

A book defined the following matrix $(a_{ij})_{3\times 3}$ :

$a_{ij}=\begin{cases} d_{ij}& i\neq j\\d_{ii}+\sum_{j=1}^3 d_{ij}&i=j\end{cases}$

where $d_{ij}$ are elements defined for $1\le i,j\le 3$.

I dont understand the case for $i=j$

Does it mean $d_{11}=d_{11}+d_{12}+d_{13}$?

Comment: What is k in this problem? You haven't defined it.

Comment: Also, not a fan of using $j$ as the dummy variable in the sum, given that $j = i$ is already fixed.

Comment: @TheoBendit,i have edited the question,can you help now

Comment: @DonThousand,can you help now,i have edited it

Comment: Why the downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [Theo Bendit](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/248286/theo-bendit)'s comment re: the reuse of a variable in the summation, as it tends to confuse people. Thus, I will rephrase it to give that, for $i = j$, the notation means $a_{ii} = d_{ii} + \sum_{k=1}^3 d_{ik} = d_{ii} + d_{i1} + d_{i2} + d_{i3}$. Thus, for example, $a_{11} = d_{11} + d_{11} + d_{12} + d_{13} = 2d_{11} + d_{12} + d_{13}$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{aligned}
a_{11} & = d_{11} + d _{11} + d_{12} + d _{13} \\
a_{12} & = d_{12} \\
a_{13} & = d_{13} \\
a_{21} & = d_{21} \\
a_{22} & = d_{22} + d _{21} + d_{22} + d _{23} \\
a_{23} & = d_{23} \\
a_{31} & = d_{31} \\
a_{32} & = d_{32} \\
a_{33} & = d_{33} + d _{31} + d_{32} + d _{33}
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 0):

> We have for $1\leq i,j\leq 3$
>
> \begin{align*}
> a_{ij}&=
> \begin{cases} 
> d_{ij}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad i\neq j\\
> d_{ii}+\sum_{\color{blue}{j}=1}^3 d_{i\color{blue}{j}}\quad\qquad i=j
> \end{cases}\tag{1}\\
> &=
> \begin{cases} 
> d_{ij}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad i\neq j\\
> d_{ii}+\left(\sum_{\color{blue}{j}=1}^3 d_{i\color{blue}{j}}\right)\quad\,\,\,\, i=j
> \end{cases}\tag{2}\\
> &=
> \begin{cases} 
> d_{ij}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad i\neq j\\
> d_{ii}+\sum_{k=1}^3 d_{ik}\quad\qquad i=j
> \end{cases}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> These variants are all valid and represent the same.
>
> - In (1) and (2) readability is reduced somewhat due to the multiple usage of  $j$,  on the one hand as *[bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables#Examples)* index    variable   and on the other hand  as  *[free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables#Examples)* variable.
> - The scope of the index variable $\color{blue}{j}$ is indicated in (2)  by parenthesis.